# Excel find duplicates, adding their values and delete row

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with duplicate names and numbers. I have to find the duplicate names with an Excel macro. Then i have to count the total costs and finally delete the duplicates.

Here's an example of the original sheet:

[image]

This should be the results:

[image]

Is there a **macro** for this?

Comment: Use a Pivot table, no need to do code anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a pivot table using the original table as a source. Set the Number aggregation to average and costs to sum.

Comment: They are great for when the data is properly structured (i.e. is tabular, such as in your case).